# pandas: access MultiColumn values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataset `df` that looks like this:

[image]

I want to calculate the proportion of listings that are `True`, for each neighbourhood.

How can I do this?

I was assuming I could do something like:

```
df['total'] = df.listing_id.True + df.listing_id.False
df['percent_true'] = df.listing_id.True / df.total * 100
```

But it seems not: I get `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'True'`.

UPDATE: Here's some data, as requested (though I don't know how to turn it into a MultiColumn):

```
data = [
  { 'neighbourhood': 'Barking and Dagenham', False: 795, True: 0 },
  { 'neighbourhood': 'Barnet', False: 6451, True: 0 },
  { 'neighbourhood': 'Bexley', False: 704, True: 0 },
  { 'neighbourhood': 'Brent', False: 13681, True: 576 }
  { 'neighbourhood': 'Bromley', False: Bromley, True: 0 }
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: You should use a different column name than `True` and `False`, Since they are builtin constants in python

Comment: @GarbageCollector thanks - not sure how to rename them! (searching 'rename multicolumn pandas' not enlightening either)

Comment: Some code to reproduce this dataframe, if possible?

Comment: Aha - worked out how to regenerate the dataframe and it works fine with non-reserved column names. Thanks @GarbageCollector!